# Sorting List of String by their rank

Tags: c#

Given a

```
List<string> s=new List<string>{"a","b","c"}
and 
List<double> srank=new List<double>{2,3,1}
```

I wish to sort `s` by the number of `srank` in descending order i.e. after sorting

```
s={"b","a","c"}
```

what's the easiest way for doing this？

Comment: Any reason you aren't storing these as objects instead of 2 lists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
   var sorted = s
      .Zip(srank, (x,y) => new { s = x, rank = y })
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.rank)
      .Select(x => x.s)
      .ToList();
```

Read more about [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx)

Read more about [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx)

EDIT:

There is a very short solution using arrays:
if `s` and `srank` were Arrays we can do this:

```
Array.Sort(srank,s);
```

Comment: s = x; rank = y; part give me error=>',' or '}' expected

Comment: @william007 sorry edited, there was a typo :) thanks for mentioning

Comment: @wudzik Still a `;` to much though :)

Comment: @flindeberg ah, thanks, writing without IDE is pain in the ... :)

Comment: Your example using Array.Sort() has the parameters the wrong way around.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks, good point edit

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd use a `List<Tuple>` a `Dictionary` or create a new `class` then do

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>
{
    { "a", 2 },
    { "b", 3 },
    { "c", 1 }
};

var result = dictionary.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value).Select(d => d.Key);
```

Comment: a bit overkill I think

Comment: Depends on the situation. Not knowing what the code is for, this is a viable alternative.

Comment: maybe you are right, it depends ;)